# What game is this with a purple room?

Tags: game-identification

[image: A bedroom with a character facing away from the camera]

Google reverse image search times out. I found the image in this article and my friend recognized it. We can't figure out what the name of the game is or what it was about. My friend says you could pick up a few items in this room (the game started here). You could also go downstairs and talk to some people and go even further down to the basement. Sorry, that's all the info we got...

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Google reverse search (not sure why it failed for you) brings up
[Flight of the amazon queen](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=isch&q=flight%20of%20the%20amazon%20queen&oq=&gs_l=)

Comment: Awesome, that's it! (he says) :)