# What game is this picture showing a teenage girl wearing a shirt with three yellow birds from?

Tags: game-identification

What game is this picture from?

[image: A teenage girl in a room, wearing a shirt with three yellow bird-like creatures]

Google reverse image search times out. I found the image in an article and my friend recognized it. We can't figure out what the name of the game is or what it was about.

Comment: `Google reverse image search times out` <-- Huh? How?

Comment: you can buy that shirt here http://www.redbubble.com/people/thebrander/works/18071792-life-is-strange-max-pjs?grid_pos=6&p=t-shirt&style=womens

Comment: You used almost the exact same wording [as I did](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/179950/what-game-is-this) with the same question for a different game!

Answer (score 68):

The image is from [Life is Strange](http://www.lifeisstrange.com/agegate.php), by Dontnod Entertainment.

Life is Strange is an interactive story, in a similar style to Telltale games, about Max Caulfield, a teenage girl with the power to rewind time.

Comment: @user143946 it's also an incredible game.

Comment: Also strange (at least to me) that they provide [a public `phpinfo` page](http://www.lifeisstrange.com/phpinfo.php).

Comment: @UweKeim haha that is weird, we should email webmaster@eidos.com I guess

Comment: It's also (barely) worth nothing that the image shown is mirrored. http://i.imgur.com/ZC0oY7L.png

Comment: @UweKeim just for the record, Dontnod does not manage that website :-)

Answer (score 7):

This might be Life is Strange. I'm not sure, but it does look very similar.